How to fix third party launcher frozen in samsung foldable phone
I am making a third party Launcher base on Launcher3 open source. While I am testing it on Samsung Fold 5, I usually get frozen for a few seconds or sometime need to restart it. This is the way i repeat this issue:

Set my launcher to default
Open a random application
Fold in the phone but not open the small screen
Then fold out and swipe to home screen
Now my Launcher still get all the event and work well, except that nothing redraw so it feel like frozen.

I tested it with many other third party Launcher and it get same problem, even Nova Launcher, Microsoft Launcher, .... Only DNA launcher don't have that problem, so someone can show me how they can fix it. Thanks!
I try with an empty activity set to launcher_app and it has same problem, so I can confirm that is not my bad when customize the open source.
Here is my empty activity AndroidManifest.xml with some clickable view inside to check if it got frozen:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER_APP" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>




Please edit your post and include the code of your empty Activity and manifest where you can reproduce the freeze.
